# Preload image resources using .NET/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, asynchronous, preload

I want to preload my image resources when the application is starting. The images should be cached in the application memory. So I can use
the preloaded images in my application.

The problem, if I load a specific View with a lot of images inside,
the application hangs a few seconds, after that the view will appear.
The application is [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language)-based, but the source-property of the image-controls is dynamically changed.

I've tested a few things, but nothing seems to work.

```
var uri = new Uri ( "pack://application:,,,/Vibrafit.Demo;component/Resources/myImage.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute ); //unit.Image1Uri;
var src = new BitmapImage ( uri );
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
src.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;

src.DownloadFailed += delegate {
    Console.WriteLine ( "Failed" );
};

src.DownloadProgress += delegate {
    Console.WriteLine ( "Progress" );
};

src.DownloadCompleted += delegate {
    Console.WriteLine ( "Completed" );
};
```

but the image will not load. The only way to load the image is to show it on the screen within a Image-Control and assign the Source-Property to my newly created BitmapImage-Object. But I don't want to show all images at the startup.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image to be loaded immediately, you need to set this cache option:

```
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
```

Otherwise, it's loaded on demand the first time you access the data (or, in your case, every time you try to access the image data, since you are choosing `None`).

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also, you are setting the `UriSource` *before* setting the cache options. So try something like (out of my head, can't test right now):

```
var uri = new Uri ( "pack://application:,,,/Vibrafit.Demo;component/Resources/myImage.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute ); //unit.Image1Uri;
var src = new BitmapImage ();
src.BeginInit();
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
src.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
src.DownloadFailed += delegate {
    Console.WriteLine ( "Failed" );
};

src.DownloadProgress += delegate {
    Console.WriteLine ( "Progress" );
};

src.DownloadCompleted += delegate {
    Console.WriteLine ( "Completed" );
};
src.UriSource = uri;
src.EndInit();
```

Comment: Hi, I've tested all options. Also OnLoad. But it doesn't work.
I need a method to load the BitmapImage, also when the Image is not being displayed.

Regards

Comment: The problem is that you are setting the `UriSource` before setting the cache options (in the constructor parameter). See my edit. Sorry, can't test it right now, but I guess that's the problem.

Comment: I have added a answer. Below my Question.